# How to validate string field in a rest request against enum value?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, enums

I am implementing a controller class in a spring-boot project and want to validate retrieved model of post method. It has a string field and should be validated against an enum value.
I wonder is there any validation annotation which will get enum class and check if value has a valid enum value? For example :

```
class ModelObject{
  @EnumValidator(MyEnumClass.class)
  String inputField;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply specify the Enum as your @RequestParam, it will validate against the values present in enum.

Additionally, if you are using swagger-ui, this is bound to the values of the enum field.

Comment: I would like validate request body, not the request parameter